# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT after 4 devices using same web site

Tags: networking, google-chrome, http

I have a user where when they have more than one computer/device make http requests to a site; it gets error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. The server is not blocking or rate limiting and under very little load. It then works about 1 minute later.

I am starting to think it is router/ISP as no one else is reporting and same behavior has happened with 2 hosting companies.

```
root@host [~]# uptime
 17:22:16 up 298 days,  6:39,  2 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.06, 0.03
```

What things can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: This is a complete punt, but is the website hosted on a Linux box? If so, check whether tcp_tw_recylcle is turned on (`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle`). Having it on can result in failed connections when multiple devices behind a NAT device try to connect to the server.

Comment: It is set to "0"